# How to retrieve json data from php

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

i want to retrive json data from php with ajax and output it for test. but it did not work.

Client index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>kakak</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.name;
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "json.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this's json.php already have object.

```
<?php

$myArray = ["name" => "john", "age" => 30, "city" => "Japan"];

$myObj = json_encode($myArray);

?>
```

I want to retrieve object name but it dont ouput anything.

Comment: @TheCodesee what do  you mean anyway? object i want retrieve in json.php.

Comment: @TheCodesee `{"name":"john","age":30,"city":"Japan"}` this's the object.

Comment: So this is what you should receive in js.

Comment: Use "JSON.parse()" in js.

Comment: @hossam i already use it in my ajax call. but it return nothing. can u look my client code?

Comment: ! Then check the browser at client side for any errors (F12/Inspect element at Chrome).

Comment: How did we miss this !.
You need to ECHO the $myObj in PHP.

Comment: @hossam lol, i dont think it too. but i still think why we need to echo it. why it cant directly call the data. thank anyway

Comment: You need to echo so the data is printed at the output. The ajax calls ordinary GET request as if you just opened the page from your browser.

Comment: @hossam by the way, is it safe to use json data in client side?. i plan to retrieve mysql trough json and use it in client side for validation user input . is will open some malicious attack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to echo the JSON string in PHP code.

```
echo $myObj;
```

Final code would be:

```
<?php

$myArray = ["name" => "john", "age" => 30, "city" => "Japan"];
$myObj = json_encode($myArray);
echo $myObj;
// or directly
// echo json_encode($myArray);
?>
```

Comment: thanks, by the way. by your respective. is it safe to use json data in client side? i plan to convert mysql database to json and play in client side for validating data when login and activation. is it safe?

Comment: @jarwobangun :  what you mean by _"client side for validating"_ ?